# Anaconda error and OSError: could not find or load spatialindex_c.dll

Tags: python-3.x

I am facing "OSError: could not find or load spatialindex_c.dll" error whenever importing any uninstalled module e.g. geopandas,earthpy in Jupyter notebook.
Moreover, when I install any module using anaconda i face several issues.
First of all, Upon openning and activating the base environment i find this warning.

C:\Users>activate base
The system cannot find the path specified.

C:\Users>set "GDAL_DRIVER_PATH="

(base) C:\Users>conda --version
conda 4.7.10

Secondly, while using conda to install a module e.g. numpy i face this kind of problem.
(geo) C:\Users\Jarin Tasnim>conda install -c anaconda numpy
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done

### Package Plan

environment location: C:\Users\Jarin Tasnim\Anaconda3\envs\geo

added / updated specs:
    - numpy

The following packages will be downloaded:

```
package                    |            build
---------------------------|-----------------
certifi-2019.6.16          |           py36_0         155 KB  anaconda
numpy-1.15.4               |   py36ha559c80_0          36 KB  anaconda
------------------------------------------------------------
                                       Total:         190 KB
```

The following packages will be UPDATED:

certifi              pkgs/main::certifi-2018.10.15-py36_0 --> anaconda::certifi-2019.6.16-py36_0

The following packages will be SUPERSEDED by a higher-priority channel:

numpy                                           pkgs/main --> anaconda

Proceed ([y]/n)? y

Downloading and Extracting Packages
certifi-2019.6.16    | 155 KB    |                                                |   0%
numpy-1.15.4         | 36 KB     |                                                |   0%

[WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
[WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application

Should i install anaconda again?

Comment: Try this 'conda install -c conda-forge osmnx'

Comment: Thanks for the reply.Tried that already but didnt solve the issue.Meanwhile i have reinstalled anaconda. I have installed geopandas again.after that having the same problem. C:\Users>activate base The system cannot find the path specified.

C:\Users>set "GDAL_DRIVER_PATH="